Installing Ubuntu on a Dell Latitude E6430 running Windows 7 Pro
I bought a few used Dell Latitude laptops. Two are E6430 and two are E6530. All but one of these laptops are running Windows 7 Pro.  These will be my first Linux computers. I want to install the latest LTS of Ubuntu as the only OS on the machines. I have been checking online and found some website information and videos that are sort of close to what I'm going to do except they either had another kind of BIOS or they were different Dell models (like Inspiron, XPS).  The few Latitude videos I found that were closest just glossed over the necessary pre-installation BIOS settings and focused more on the actual installation setup. Funny, I would think that configuring Ubuntu by following the installation wizard is the easy part and pre-configuring the BIOS to allow the installation in the first place is the hard part. Whatever....
I want to know what parameters need to be changed in the BIOS.  I know that my BIOS is set to Legacy now and I am guessing that I need to disable secure boot. Do I need to select UEFI or can I install using Legacy? Does it matter?  Aside from changing the boot order are there any other BIOS changes needed?  I've heard that older machines like these may not boot from a USB drive as easily as they would from a DVD drive.
Will the install Ubuntu option (first item in GRUB list) automatically format the drive or do I need to pre-format a partition.  I don't want a dual boot Windows 7 laptop, only Ubuntu as the OS. Thanks very much for your help!!

Just flash Ubuntu on a USB drive and boot the computer from it. Then install it. There is no need to change BIOS/UEFI settings.

FYI:  I have ~25 boxes I use in QA, and there is great variation within brands, more so if you include other brands...  the machine firmware dictates how a machine responds, so if one has updated firmware it can boot live media or be different to another that wasn't updated but is the identical make/model... Ubuntu products install in legacy BIOS, uEFI or Secure-Boot uEFI if ISO is written correctly OR if you reformat ISO you maybe only able to install in one way.  If you install your systems with uEFI secure-boot enabled; you can always turn it off; reverse does not apply!

Really??? That's it?  I see lots of information about secure boot, UEFI and other settings that others change.

You also mention Ubuntu, but Ubuntu comes in various products & releases (you did indicate Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, but didn't specify Server or Desktop, as they use different installers, plus there are flavors which can vary too).    I'll suggest following documented ISO writing procedures; as many ISO writers allow reformatting of ISO which changes things; QA is done with a simple clone (ie. unchanging write to install media; no reformat), so many complications are caused by ISO write to install media (ie. thumb-drive)..

Archisman- Really?? So there is nothing to pre-configure in BIOS.  I see alot of posts and videos where people pre-configure the BIOS.  But, OK, I'll give it a try.  Thanks!!

The "How do I install Ubuntu?" info is either dual boot or different Win OS (possibly different BIOS) or different computer.  I know there is someone on this plant who has done exactly what I want to do.  I have enough experience to know that "close to what I want to do" may not work.

Hi guiverc- I have 4 Dell laptops that I want the latest Ubuntu LTS version.  No flavors no server setup.  Just laptop (desktop) stations.

The Wifi card in all of them are Broadcom (Dell 1540) cards.  I will also be swapping out these cards for newer Intel 7260.HMW Dual Band WiFi cards with bluetooth.  I assume  proper drivers will get installed by Ubuntu during the setup process.
